# Java Recursive Method Count the paths way of street

Tags: java, recursion

This only can go east and south. 
For example,1 block east and 2 blocks south, then it has the total paths ways are: 
1 block east and 2 blocks south,
1 block east, then 2 blocks south
1 block south, then 1 block east, then 1 block south
2 blocks south, then 1 block east

How about 6 blocks east, 6 blocks south.

My code are:

```
public class Path{
    public static int numPaths(int east, int south){

        if( (east==1)&&(south==1)){
            return 2;
        }
        if ((east==1)&&(south==2)){
            return 3;
        }
        else{
        return (numPaths(east,south-1)+numPaths(south-1,east));
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(numPaths(6,6));
    }
}
```

( However this doesn't work, it complains my code at the last line of METHOD, I Just don't know how to fix it.)
I want to know reason, not the answer.

Comment: Please re format code for better readability and attach error message.

Comment: @maxhb Thanks, the error is : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at Path.numPaths(Path.java:12)
 at Path.numPaths(Path.java:12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you really should chain your `if`s together using `else if`.

The real problem however is that you don't have any checks that make sure that values never go under 1. Because of this you get infinite recursion with smaller and smaller values.

Add an `if` block checking this:

```
if ((east==1) && (south==1)){
    return 2;
} else if ((east==1) && (south==2)){
    return 3;
} else if ((east==0) || (south==0)) {
    return 0;
} else {
    return (numPaths(east,south-1)+numPaths(south-1,east));
}
```

Comment: Wonderful! (Y) It prints out 378! (Y)

Comment: @Keppil:  Mystery test case was failed

Comment: @LiEdXiaolong: Then you probably need to adjust the base cases. This solves the problem with the StackOverflowError, but I can't give you the exact answer since I don't have the question (and you didn't want the exact question).

Answer (score 0):

> Exception : java.lang.StackOverflowError
>   \

Where is the tail of recursion. I mean I don't find the recursion ending anywhere. This 
`if(east == 0 || south ==0){return value;}` is required